# Remove ads malware from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, malware, adware

A malware smuggled its way into my chrome. It ads ad JS snippet into footer, before  tag:

[image]

However, what's peculiar is that I found that it only injects itself into one website:

http://www.fabrika.org.rs/coworking/

It doesn't seem that the code originates from the website itself, as the code is not there when I use Microsoft Edge, and I also checked it with an online source viewer tool:

http://www.generateit.net/seo-tools/source-viewer/

And it came back without the snippet. How do I trace and remove this malware?

Comment: Does `Iklan Telkom Indihome / Telkom Speedy` these words ring any bell ? What extensions are you using ? If this is limited to chrome, its as simple as resetting it or just creating a new chrome profile

Comment: It seems to be related to Indonesia (where I currently am), but if it was ISP injected , it should show up everywhere? Modules haven't installed anything new in a while. Will resetting chrome profile remove all my settings, history, bookmarks, etc ?

Comment: settings, history, cookies and session will be deleted but bookmarks will be unaffected. Also you can always export your bookmarks. [Try creating a new chrome profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en) for a while and see if this fixes it, if it does, start using it. move your bookmarks there else just undo/delete new profile

Comment: Are you with this ISP ? `Iklan Telkom Indihome`

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to reset Chrome. 
Goto settings > Search "Reset" > Reset.

This will reset the chrome environment

[image]

Comment: This does not remove all malwares

Answer (score -1):

To remove ads malware from chrome you need to:

- Use the Chrome cleanup tool which will remove the unwanted browser changes
- Scan your computer with anti-malware software

To remove Chrome adware and browser hijackers, you can use HitmanPro

Comment: This generic answer is not useful. You could improve it by explaining how the cleaning tool works and how to use it.